# Windows 10 doesn't recognize my 2nd hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I have Windows 7 in a SSD, a 1 TB WD Blue hard drive and another SSD with Windows 10. I physically swap between win7 SSD and win10 ssd whenever I want to switch to another OS.

The Win10 does not recognize my WD HDD. It does not appear on "this PC", but it appears on disk management and on device manager. Everything seems ok, but the disk doesn't mount. On Win7 it works perfectly.

I think it gotta do with something related to last state of win7 stored in the drive? (tried mounting on Ubuntu and a windows related error appeared suggesting to run windows and propperly shut down). I always shut down, never suspend.

Comment: Is the drive initialized, a thread at Tom's mentions a Western Digital Blue and similar circumstances like yours.

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3284968/blue-1tb-drive-recognized.html

Comment: assign a drive letter to the drive in disk management gui

Comment: Thanks, manually asigned a letter and started working. Thanks